# How to know the exact size of a Picker in an View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos, ipados

To precisely know the View's architecture, and how to compose it, it will be useful to know what size will get the Picker in the parent View. Is this predictable ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to constraint a Picker to a specific width; but if I do not any frame, or clipped modifier, on the screen of any device, then what will be the size, width and height, of the Picker ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I really understand the question, but you can give the Picker frame like.

```
       VStack {
        Picker("Colors", selection: $selectedColor) {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 10)
        .clipped()
```

Or you can use GeometryReader

Comment: Thanks, but what about the size of the Picker without constraint ? On any screen device ?

Comment: it depends on what you need to do. Just use the GeometryReader to get width and height of the Picker.